# How can I get file or directory list from the resources in the jar?

Tags: java

[image]
How can I get file or directory list from the resources in the jar?
such as [insights,openapi]
such as [20221102.json, 20221103.json].

Comment: A jar is actually a zip. Use a lib to read the zip file content.

Comment: If it's from a jar on your classpath you can try `ClassLoader.getResources(...)` etc. - Note that the content of "resources" is normally packaged into a jar at root level, so "featureconfig" would be your first path element.

Comment: A jar is actually a zip. Use a lib to read the zip file content.

It has worked

Answer (score -1):

A jar is actually a zip. Use a lib to read the zip file content.
The read zip code, getZipFileList

```
String path = Application.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
        log.info("path: " + path);
        String replace = path.replace("/classes", "");
        if (!replace.contains("/resource-script.jar")) {
            replace = replace + "/resource-script.jar";
        }
        List<String> zipFileList2 = getZipFileList(replace);



public static List<String> getZipFileList(String zipFileName) throws IOException {
    ZipInputStream zipInputStream = null;
    try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(zipFileName)) {
        zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(
                new BufferedInputStream(inputStream), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        java.util.zip.ZipEntry ze;
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        //循环遍历
        while ((ze = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            if (!ze.isDirectory()) {
                list.add(ze.getName());
            }
        }
        return list;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.info(" getZipOneFileContent error:" + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (zipInputStream != null) {
            zipInputStream.closeEntry();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Also, the site behind this link is not in English. So most of further visitors cannot read the content.